# How to make sure a bounded form and subform in MS Access only submits to the database after a button click?

Tags: forms, ms-access, subform

A little information about the problem, I am fixing an old Access database that has a form bounded to a table "tblMain" and the subform is bounded to a table "tblSub" and the relationship between tblMain to tblSub is one to many, where tblSub has a field called belongs_to which is the id field of the record in tblMain that owns it.

So the main form holds one record and the subform holds many records that are tied to that one main record.

Is there any way for me to tell the two forms to wait to update to the database until after a button has been pressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way to do what you are asking for. It basically comes down to use unbound forms and manually handling the inserts/updates.

I think you could possibly do this with an ADO recordset that is opened using adLockBatchOptimistic but I don't have a concrete answer on this.

I recommend you stick with the default behavior of MS Access or consider developing your solution in .Net where batch updating is the default behavior.

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much what everyone is saying. Thanks though